# entries in the toc from printindex

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing

I want the entries in the `TOC` for the indices to align with the Chapter entries. I can do this with `\addcontents`. `\printindex` also puts an entry in the `TOC` but it is aligned with the section entries.

So I want to:

1. change how `printindex` makes its entry into the `TOC` or
2. to eliminate `printindex` entry.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multind}        % create the indices
\makeindex{names}           
\makeindex{subject}
\newcommand{\Ndx}[1] { \index{names}{#1} }     % define the type of entry
\newcommand{\Sdx}[1] { \index{subject}{#1} }   % to the indices
\usepackage[headings]{fullpage}         % 8-1/2, 11 page with 1" margins
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\tableofcontents        % put table of contents here

\chapter{\bf Logic, Plausibility, and Probability}
\label{Ch:Logic}
\section{Logical Arguments and Reasoning }
It is obvious that logical arguments are essential to the judicial system. The logic must be able to treat syllogisms\Sdx{syllogism} that range from deductive\Sdx{syllogism!deductive} to abductive\Sdx{syllogism!abductive}, that is from strong to weak syllogisms \Sdx{syllogism!weak}\Sdx{syllogism!strong} as illustrated in the table taken from Author \Ndx{Author}
\Ndx{Cohen}
\Sdx{Cohen on probability}
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Subject Index}
\printindex{subject}{Subject Index}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Name Index}
\printindex{names}{Name Index}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can patch `\printindex` so the entries are typeset as chapter entries instead of the default (as secion entries):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multind}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}  

\patchcmd{\printindex}
  {section}
  {chapter}
  {}
  {}
      % create the indices
\makeindex{names}           
\makeindex{subject}
\newcommand{\Ndx}[1] { \index{names}{#1} }     % define the type of entry
\newcommand{\Sdx}[1] { \index{subject}{#1} }   % to the indices
\usepackage[headings]{fullpage}         % 8-1/2, 11 page with 1" margins
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\tableofcontents        % put table of contents here

\chapter{\bf Logic, Plausibility, and Probability}
\label{Ch:Logic}
\section{Logical Arguments and Reasoning }
It is obvious that logical arguments are essential to the judicial system. The logic must be able to treat syllogisms\Sdx{syllogism} that range from deductive\Sdx{syllogism!deductive} to abductive\Sdx{syllogism!abductive}, that is from strong to weak syllogisms \Sdx{syllogism!weak}\Sdx{syllogism!strong} as illustrated in the table taken from Author \Ndx{Author}
\Ndx{Cohen}
\Sdx{Cohen on probability}
\clearpage
\printindex{subject}{Subject Index}
\printindex{names}{Name Index}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `\bf` is an old TeX command which shouldn't be used anymore in modern LaTeX documents; use `\bfseries` instead. Additionally, using `\bf` (or `\bfseries`) inside the argument for `\chapter` makes no difference since in the `book` class chapter headings are already boldfaced; to change the formatting for sectional unit headings, you can use a dedicated package such as `sectsty` or `titlesec`.

Using the [`imakeidx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) package, there's no need to patch commands:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}  

\makeindex[name=names,title=Name Index,intoc=true]          
\makeindex[name=subject,title=Subject Index,intoc=true]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Logic, Plausibility, and Probability}
\section{Logical Arguments and Reasoning }

\index[names]{Cohen}
\index[subject]{Cohen on probability}
\printindex[subject]
\printindex[names]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or use `imakeidx`, of course.

Comment: @egreg I'll add an option with `imakeidx` to my answer in some minutes (unless you're planning to write an answer yourself) :-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Please, go forth.

Comment: @egreg option added.

Comment: @lockstep yes, I was just editing to delete that line.

Comment: There's no document text in your example, which may confuse some users.

Answer (score 1):

In case the [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etoolbox) package isn't available to you, or this is the only reason you're loading the package, you can actually get away without it.

The relevant part of the code from `mutlind.sty` can be modified to

```
\makeatletter
\def\printindex#1#2{\@restonecoltrue\if@twocolumn\@restonecolfalse\fi
  \columnseprule \z@ \columnsep 35pt
  \newpage \twocolumn[{\Large\bf #2 \vskip4ex}]
  \markright{\uppercase{#2}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}%   <---- NEW BIT
  \@input{#1.ind}}
```

All you have to do is change `section` to `chapter`.

Here's a complete MWE to play with- note that I have included the [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) directives so that you simply have to run

```
arara myfile
```

and you'll get a complete `pdf`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex: {files: [names]}
% arara: makeindex: {files: [subject]}
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multind}        % create the indices
\makeindex{names}           
\makeindex{subject}
\newcommand{\Ndx}[1] { \index{names}{#1} }     % define the type of entry
\newcommand{\Sdx}[1] { \index{subject}{#1} }   % to the indices

\makeatletter
\def\printindex#1#2{\@restonecoltrue\if@twocolumn\@restonecolfalse\fi
  \columnseprule \z@ \columnsep 35pt
  \newpage \twocolumn[{\Large\bf #2 \vskip4ex}]
  \markright{\uppercase{#2}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
  \@input{#1.ind}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents        % put table of contents here

\chapter{Logic, Plausibility, and Probability}\label{Ch:Logic}
\section{Logical Arguments and Reasoning }
It is obvious that logical arguments are essential to the judicial system. The logic must be able to treat syllogisms\Sdx{syllogism} that range from deductive\Sdx{syllogism!deductive} to abductive\Sdx{syllogism!abductive}, that is from strong to weak syllogisms \Sdx{syllogism!weak}\Sdx{syllogism!strong} as illustrated in the table taken from Author \Ndx{Author}
\Ndx{Cohen}
\Sdx{Cohen on probability}
\clearpage
\printindex{subject}{Subject Index}
\printindex{names}{Name Index}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The worst part about `multind` is not the fixed ToC entry, but the formatting of the index heading itself.

Comment: I use PcTex6 and imakeidx and etools are incompatible in that they abort since they are not running under e-tex.  The change to multind did exactly what I wanted.